# Создание ярлыка в xfce

Tags: linux, bash, debian, xfce, gparted

собираю .deb пакет с программой gparted. Есть необходимость написать пост-скрипт на bash (тот, что автоматически выполняется после установки .deb пакета, не помню точный термин), который бы создавал ярлык и пункт в меню с данной программой в окружении xfce4. Хотелось бы как можно подробнее узнать какие файлы и в каких директориях он должен создавать и вообще подробнее о том, как в xfce реализованы ярлыки и пункты меню. Не столько интересует готовое решение, сколько ссылки по теме, поскольку нагуглить не удалось

Comment: «ярлык» называется desktop-файлом (*desktop entry*). Его формат описывается в FDO'шной спецификации: [Desktop Entry Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html), а детали для пунктов меню в [Desktop Menu Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html)... но на практике можно просто посмотреть примеры для других приложений у себя в `/usr/share/applications/`. И, если что, это всё так безотносительно конкретного DE...

Comment: https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-opersys.html#menus